# How to send a video in chunks from a hapi js server

Tags: node.js, video, stream, hapi.js, react-native-video

I'm setting up a node js server built with hapi js framework. I created an endpoint which reads a video file from my server then sends back the chunk of data to the client. I'm using a react native on my client. I want to have a seamless video streaming from my nodejs server to my mobile app.

I tried reading the file and sending it back to the client, but it takes time because It is downloading all the data first then sending it back to the client.

```
const { filename } = req.params;
const readStream = fs.createReadStream(`uploads/videos/${filename}.mp4`);
  readStream.on('open',function(){
    //start to read de video 
  console.log("start..");
  });//open

  readStream.on('data',function(chunk){
  console.log("loading...", chunk)
  });//loading

  readStream.on("end",function(){
  console.log("ready");
  });//end 

  readStream.on('error', function (err){
  console.log(err);
  });
  return h.response(readStream)
    .type('video/mp4')
    .header('Content-type', 'video/mp4')
    .header("Accept-Ranges", "bytes")
    .header('Content-length', readStream.length);
```